# Combine physical files and dynamic files to one file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to combine a bunch of files to one "file". But I also need some of those files to be dynamic, so I have actions which return dynamic resources. E.g.

```
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "culture", Duration = 3600)]
public ActionResult Settings(string culture)
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo;
    try
    {
        cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(culture);
    }
    catch
    {
        cultureInfo = Configuration.Current.DefaultCulture;
    }
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("Cms.Settings.Language = '{0}';", cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName);

    sb.AppendFormat("Cms.Settings.DayNames = [{0}];", string.Join(",", cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.DayNames.Select(d => "\"" + d + "\"")));
    sb.AppendFormat("Cms.Settings.ShortDayNames = [{0}];", string.Join(",", cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames.Select(d => "\"" + d + "\"")));
    sb.AppendFormat("Cms.Settings.FirstDay = {0};", (int)cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);

    sb.AppendFormat("Cms.Settings.ShortMonthNames = [{0}];", string.Join(",", cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames.Take(12).Select(m => "\"" + m + "\"")));

    var languages = new[]{cultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName};
    var keys = translator.GetKeys(languages[0]);
    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("Cms.Settings.Texts['{0}'] = '{1}';", key, translator.GetText(key, key, languages));
    }

    // TODO: from settings
    sb.AppendFormat("Cms.Settings.IconDir = '{0}';", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/img/icons/"));
    return JavaScript(sb.ToString());
}
```

What I want to do is combine those physical files and ActionResults to one "file". I have made this action to do the combining, but I don't know an easy way to get the output of an action by path.

```
// files is like "jquery.js,/js/settings?culture=fi,jquery-ui.js,..."
[OutputCache(VaryByParam = "files", Duration=3600)]
public ActionResult Bundle(string files)
{
    var paths = files.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        appendFile(sb, path);
    }
    return JavaScript(sb.ToString());
}
private void appendFile(StringBuilder sb, string path)
{
    if (/* path is file on disk */)
    {
        var filename = Server.MapPath(path);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
        {
            return;
        }
        sb.Append(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename));
    }
    else if(/* is action */)
    {
        // how do I get the output?
        var output = getActionOutput(path);
        sb.Append(output);
    }
}
```

Another option I tried was to use VirtualPathProvider for dynamic files, but for some reason the "GetFile" wasn't called for files which weren't on the disk.

```
public class JsVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
{
    public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
    {
        if (virtualPath == "~/js/settings/fi.js")
        {
            // this was called
            return true;
        }
        return base.FileExists(virtualPath);
    }
    public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
    {
        // never called for this "file"?
        if (virtualPath == "~/js/settings/fi.js")
        {
                return new JsFile(virtualPath, "Cms.Settings.Foo = 'Bar';");
        }
        return base.GetFile(virtualPath);
    }

    class JsFile : VirtualFile
    {
        private readonly string content;
        public JsFile(string virtualPath, string content) : base(virtualPath)
        {
                this.content = content;
        }
        public override Stream Open()
        {
                return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content), false);
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the easiest way to combine physical files with dynamic/virtual files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output of an action with the following code.

```
var url = string.Format("{0}://{1}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host);
if (Request.Url.Port != 80)
{
    url += ":" + Request.Url.Port;
}
url += path;
var writer = new StringWriter(sb);
var httpContext = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", url, ""), new HttpResponse(writer));
HttpContextBase httpContextBase = new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext);
var routeData = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContextBase);
var handler = RouteData.RouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(new RequestContext(httpContextBase,routeData));
handler.ProcessRequest(httpContext);
```

For some reason the QueryStringValueProvider in the called action (Settings) had the values of the calling action (Bundle) so I changed the path to `/js/settings/{culture}` (previously `/js/settings?culture={culture}`)

Answer (score -1):

```
else if(/* is action */)
{
    // how do I get the output?

    // You need to send an HTTP request (for example using WebClient) 
    // to fetch the result of the execution of this action
    ...
}
```